# Storing docstrings of functions defined in any module as String

Tags: python, module, namespaces, docstring

So the deal is that i have to gather all functions and classes and whatnot from any module and display them on a webpage. Displaying them is not the hard part. The hard part is retrieving the docstrings and store them as strings. I have found a couple of ways to do it, however they are not perfect.

To elaborate, I have to do exactly what the `help()` function does in the interpreter. That is to ONLY list docstrings of the functions/classes etc defined in the module itself, NOT imported functions. I have very little clue of how `help()` it works.

First I tried this:

```py
functions_list = [o for o in getmembers(my_module) if isfunction(o[1])]
for f_name, func in function_list:
    print(func.__doc__)
```

This will get values of module's dict, and works pretty fine. All though if you import something, say `from foo import thud`, this will list `thud` as a function in `function_list`, which is not what I want to do. My other idea was to use some sort of regexing, but this will be overkill I think. There must be a better solution out there. 
Any idea of what the solution is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pyclbr` module to read the module source statically:

```
import pyclbr

for name, obj in pyclbr.readmodule_ex('my_module', ['/path/to/module']).items():
    if isinstance(obj, pyclbr.Function):
        print(name, getattr(my_module, name).__doc__)
```